# How to Count Duplicate Values in SQL based on many columns

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a larger DB that contains purchased tech devices along with accessories and for which we specify whether the client asked for assistance or no.
There are some products(belong to the same command) for which a client buys the same accessories in 2 different colors.
I need to calculate the number of products for which the same accessories is commanded in two different colors, grouped by the invoice & the major category.

[Data base sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jc85.png)

Can you please help me?

Example of such case [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwcWv.png)

I tried this code but it didn't solve it

```
SELECT `Major category`, COUNT(`Device`) FROM `tab` 
where `Invoice` IN
(select `Invoice`,`Major category`, `Device`,count(`Device`) 
from tab
group by `Invoice`,`Major category`, `Device` having count(`color`) > 1 )
GROUP BY `Major category`
```

[output excel](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16XMfE4cbqJmkChRN0HsgRG41YmgBJ56p/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=106522872491335371448&rtpof=true&sd=true)
[sample excel](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17njUukq8v6u1OrBK8aN1cSQRLlPljgMp/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106522872491335371448&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: Could you please share your simple data and expected output as text not image ? also tag the RDBMS you are using

Comment: @SelVazi working on phpMyadmin

Comment: @SelVaziI added both as excel files